# OutOfMemoryException in ReportViewer

Tags: asp.net, rdlc

I have a reportviewer, running in local mode. It just displays a list of objects, no aggreagate functions or smth hard calculations.

Our object has 27 string properties, and there are about 250000 records in database - before any filter is applied.
So reportViewer throws an OutOfMemoryException.

Linq lazy loading doesn't help us - report loads only first 50 records and even doesn't show controls for pagination

Do you have any ideas how to fix this issue? I have only one option - make one of filters required, so we will have a much smaller list of result.

But maybe there is some other better way?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have time to write a working example, but here is the gist of a possible solution.

(1) don't actually display the ReportViewer in mark up. I image that when the ReportViewer creates a large report, the whole thing is probably in memory as a byte array.

(2) Dynamically create it and then call render like so:

```
Viewer.LocalReport.Render(format, "", PageCountMode.Estimate, CreateStream, out warnings);
```

(3) Where CreateStream is the delegate like so:

```
 private Stream CreateStream(string name, string fileNameExtension, Encoding encoding,
                              string mimeType, bool willSeek)
        {
            Stream stream = new FileStream(name + "." + fileNameExtension, FileMode.Create);
            return stream;
        }
```

So the results are written to the file in a stream.  The size of the DataTable might still cause OOM exceptions, so you might want to provide the data using a DbDataReader, using this type of ReportDataSource

```
public ReportDataSource(string name, IEnumerable dataSourceValue);
```

It's possible that of the above suggestions, you only need to Switch from a DataTable to a DataReader.